# How to tell whether i am running under Ammonite repl or in a script?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, ammonite

I was trying to use different builders to build the SparkSession and [AmmoniteSparkSession](https://github.com/alexarchambault/ammonite-spark/issues/30) requires repl.

This won't work, i think it is because repl is a compile time error.

```
val sparkSessionBuilder =
  try {
    repl
    AmmoniteSparkSession.builder
  } catch {
    case e: Exception => SparkSession.builder
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

as it is compile time, we have to use the [Multi-stageScripts](https://ammonite.io/#Multi-stageScripts) to load different script according to the context. it should work something like [here](https://github.com/dyno/facets-overview-spark/blob/master/ammonites/libs/sparkSession.sc#L1)

```scala
val sparkSessionModule = sys.env.get("AMMONITE_REPL") match {
  case None => pwd / RelPath("libs/_SparkSession.sc")
  case Some(_) => pwd / RelPath("libs/_AmmoniteSparkSession.sc")
}
interp.load.module(sparkSessionModule)
@
```